# Select no mysql agrupando resultado por mês

Tags: mysql

Bom tenho a seguinte estrutura de tabela:

```
Categoria  |  DataOp        |  Tipo    | ValorOp
--------------------------------------------------
Carro      |  2012-01-14  |   1        | 10
Moto       |  2012-01-17  |   1        | 200
Venda      |  2012-03-15  |   2        | 500
Carro      |  2012-04-24  |   1        | 10
Moto       |  2012-04-10  |   1        | 35
Internet   |  2012-01-11  |   1        | 98
```

Bom quero fazer um `select` que me retorne a soma dos totais de cada mês do tipo 1:

O resultado teria que ser esse:

```
 Mes    | Total
----------------------------
 01     | 308
 04     | 45
```

Acho que o `select` ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
SELECT
    DataOp,
    SUM(ValorOp)
FROM
    ResumoReceitaDespesas
GROUP BY DataOp
```

Porém aqui ele agrupa por por mês.

--------------- Solução --------------

```
SELECT
    MONTH(DataOp),
    SUM(ValorOp)
FROM
    ResumoReceitaDespesas
WHERE Tipo = '1'
GROUP BY DataOp
```

Comment: Não entendi o agrupar por cidade. Utilize a função `MONTH()` ou talvez seja melhor `YEAR()` e `MONTH()`.

Comment: Eu me atrapalhei no final da pergunta. De qualquer forma sua solução deu certo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu pode fazer de duas formas,

```
SELECT
    MONTH(DataOp) as Mes,
    Tipo,
    SUM(ValorOp) as TotalOp
FROM
    ResumoReceitaDespesas
GROUP BY Mes, Tipo

SELECT
    MONTH(DataOp) as Mes,
    Tipo,
    SUM(ValorOp) as TotalOp
FROM
    ResumoReceitaDespesas
WHERE Tipo = '1'
GROUP BY Mes, Tipo
```

A primeira vai trazer todos os tipos agrupados por mês e a segunda somente o primeiro tipo.